# Retrieving the reference of a class instance directly from one of its member methods that's passed as a parametre in a different class' method in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, methods, reflection

I'm developing a project in Unity. I think code sample will explain itself.

NOTES:

1. Module constructor shall not need any other parameter, such as "this" referring to a Container instance
2. Module constructor only parametre must stay as IEnumerator, not Func<> etc
3. Coroutine passed as the parameter, will not be invoked directly (for ex. StartCoroutine(...) )
4. Code logic that's inside the Module CTOR shall not be moved into a seperate method (neither public nor extension method).

   ```
    class Module
    {
            // CTOR
            public Module(IEnumerator _someCoroutine)
            {
            // This is where I need to get the reference to the
            // instance of a Container class (not "typeof(Container)")
            // which _someCoroutine method's reference is held, 
            // directly from _someCoroutine parameter
            }

    }

    class Container : MonoBehaviour
    {
         void Awake()
         {
           Module module = new Module(SomeCoroutine());
         }

            IEnumerator SomeCoroutine()
            {...}
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Afaik there's no way to do that, even if you use reflection.

IEnumerator is kind of sort of a dynamic list -- one that runs code to resolve its content, and the code technically resides inside its body, so the best you can get via reflection is some nonsense, or typeof(IEnumerator).

You can have a peek at how it looks once it compiles by playing around in sharplab:
https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwHQGED2ANoQKYDGALgJb4B2AzgNzLJQDMmM6u6A3sukHoARviLoAHugC86CgCcAriWZIh6KrQroAZjPSpV6gUICSAUVqKAtiXkBDCvnnoLV2w6fyAQiQAWmsAAKn4kABJiwAAUAJR8JuqCVHpRAIQScbyYcHAi8iT2ANaM6AC+CYkA7gGk6FF6ADzocKitqJm6YGAlWLlQAOzoVsQl5WpCY8ZIpUA===

As you see, technically there IS a reference of the container in the enumerator, but I haven't managed to obtain it (neither has anyone I know), so, if you do manage that please let me know!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I noticed that I forgot to add Awake() method in the code. I am posting the solution down below which I got from other forums.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Reflection;
class Module
{
    public Module(IEnumerator _someCoroutine)
    {
        var type = _someCoroutine.GetType();
        var fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        foreach(var f in fields)
        {
            if (f.Name.Contains("__this"))
            {
                object o = f.GetValue(_someCoroutine);
            }
            // or
            // if (typeof(MonoBehaviour).IsAssignableFrom(f.FieldType))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).